# I want to count the number of "e" characters in a string in C#

Tags: c#

Every time I run the program it keeps crashing because of this line of code:

```
if (s[i] == 'e')
```

Can anyone help me please?

```
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string:");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    int anz = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'e')
            anz++;
        else if (s[i] == 'E')
        {
            anz++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("There are" + anz + "e's in your string! ");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I know but why doesnt it work with this one? I want to do it with these commands here

Comment: change i <= s.Length to i < s.Length

Comment: The problem is in your loop. What error are you getting? Think about how many items you're iterating over.

Comment: You need to convert your string to an array first, then loop through the array. `char[] array = s.ToCharArray();`

Comment: Thanks to everyone thanks to you I managed to solve it! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

You could use Linq's `Count()` and omit all the looping and variable declarations:

```
int anz = s.Count(i => i == 'e' || i == 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= s.Length; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (s.Length-1); i++)
```

i.e. if you type 10 characters, it tries to get `s[10]` in the last loop. Indexations start from 0 and ends in Length -1.You tried to get one more letter.

Note that there are easy ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this way:

```
string search = "search the E character";
int count = 0;
foreach (var character in search.ToLower())
{
    if (character.Equals('e'))
        count += 1;
}
```